# How can I prove irreflexivity of an inductively defined relation in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, induction

Consider as an example the following definition of inequality of natural numbers in Isabelle:

```
inductive unequal :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
  zero_suc: "unequal 0 (Suc _)" |
  suc_zero: "unequal (Suc _) 0" |
  suc_suc:  "unequal n m ⟹ unequal (Suc n) (Suc m)"
```

I want to prove irreflexivity of `unequal`, that is, `¬ unequal n n`. For illustration purposes let me first prove the contrived lemma `¬ unequal (n + m) (n + m)`:

```
lemma "¬ unequal (n + m) (n + m)"
proof
  assume "unequal (n + m) (n + m)"
  then show False
  proof (induction "n + m" "n + m" arbitrary: n m)
    case zero_suc
    then show False by simp
  next
    case suc_zero
    then show False by simp
  next
    case suc_suc
    then show False by presburger
  qed
qed
```

In the first two cases, `False` must be deduced from the assumptions `0 = n + m` and `Suc _ = n + m`, which is trivial.

I would expect that the proof of `¬ unequal n n` can be done in an analogous way, that is, according to the following pattern:

```
lemma "¬ unequal n n"
proof
  assume "unequal n n"
  then show False
  proof (induction n n arbitrary: n)
    case zero_suc
    then show False sorry
  next
    case suc_zero
    then show False sorry
  next
    case suc_suc
    then show False sorry
  qed
qed
```

In particular, I would expect that in the first two cases, I get the assumptions `0 = n` and `Suc _ = n`. However, I get no assumptions at all, meaning that I am asked to prove `False` from nothing. Why is this and how can I conduct the proof of inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `induction` method handles variable instantiations and non-variable instantiations differently. A non-variable instantiation `t` is a shorthand for `x ≡ t` where `x` is a fresh variable. As a result, induction is done on `x`, and the context additionally contains the definition `x ≡ t`.

Therefore, `(induction "n + m" "n + m" arbitrary: n m)` in the first proof is equivalent to `(induction k ≡ "n + m" l ≡ "n + m" arbitrary: n m)` with the effect described above. To get this effect for the second proof, you have to replace `(induction n n arbitrary: n)` with `(induction k ≡ n l ≡ n arbitrary: n)`. The assumptions will actually become so simple that the pre-simplifier, which is run by the `induction` method, can derive `False` from them. As a result, there will be no cases left to prove, and you can replace the whole inner `proof`–`qed` block with `by (induction k ≡ n l ≡ n arbitrary: n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are inducting over `unequal`. Instead, you should induct over `n`, like this:

```
lemma "¬ (unequal n n)"
proof (induct n)
  case 0
  then show ?case sorry
next
  case (Suc n)
  then show ?case sorry
qed
```

Then we can use Sledgehammer on each of the subgoals marked with `sorry`. Sledgehammer (with CVC4) recommends us to complete the proof as follows:

```
lemma "¬ (unequal n n)"
proof (induct n)
  case 0
  then show ?case using unequal.cases by blast
next
  case (Suc n)
  then show ?case using unequal.cases by blast
qed
```

Comment: Induction over `unequal` is actually what I wanted. My actual problem is not about inequality, but bisimilarity. In this situation, the solution you describe is not really an option. And I do not understand why induction over `unequal` does not work here. After all, it worked in the example with `n + m`.

Comment: After carefully studying the part on the `induction` proof method in the Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual, I found the solution to my problem. I will answer the question myself shortly. Nevertheless, thank you for your effort.

Comment: Ok. I'm looking forward to your answer.